# Process elements after sinking to Destination

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am setting up a flink pipeline that reads from Kafka and sinks to HDFS. I want to process the elements after the addSink() step. This is because I want to setup trigger files indicating that writing data (to the sink) for a certain partition/hour is complete. How can this be achieved? Currently I am using the Bucketing sink.

1. DataStream messageStream = env
               .addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer011);
2. //some aggregations to convert message stream to keyedStream
3. keyedStream.addSink(sink);

//How to process elements after 3.?

Answer (score 1):

The Flink APIs do not support extending the job graph beyond the sink(s). (You can, however, fork the stream and do additional processing in parallel with writing to the sink.)

With the [Streaming File Sink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html#streaming-file-sink) you can observe the part files transition to the finished state when they complete. See the [JavaDoc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/filesystem/StreamingFileSink.html) for more information.

State lives within a single operator -- only that operator (e.g., a ProcessFunction) can modify it. If you want to modify the keyed value state after the sink has completed, there's no straightforward way to do that. One idea would be to add a processing time timer in the ProcessFunction that has the keyed state that wakes up periodically and checks for newly finished part files, and based on their existence, modifies the state. Or if that's the wrong granularity, write a custom source that does something similar and streams or broadcasts information into the ProcessFunction (which will then have to be a CoProcessFunction or a KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction) that it can use to do the necessary state updates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Given that I have a strong requirement for this use case, how do you recommend I go about achieving this? (I need more information than just the part files transition) For instance, I want to use the value state.

Comment: I don't follow -- what do you mean by "use the value state"?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you can define a custom rolling policy, if necessary, and observe (externally) when the files no longer have names that are ".in_progress" or ".pending".

Comment: After writing to the sink (for a keyed stream), I want to have a process function which reads/updates the keyed value state. Once I finish writing to the sink, I want to store some kind of cache/state to do additional processing.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer, now that I (hopefully) understand your question. If you provide more info about your use case, it may be possible to give better advice.

Comment: Thank you, " ProcessFunction that has the keyed state that wakes up periodically and checks for newly finished part files". How can the process function check for newly finished part files, by making file system calls?

Comment: As a friendly reminder, Streaming File Sink Flink API is now the official Flink way. BucketingSink API will eventually become deprecated. Source: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/filesystem_sink.html