# How to trigger airflow jobs based on flink streaming completion for partitions?

Tags: apache-flink, airflow, flink-streaming, lambda-architecture

I have a flink streaming job which reads from Kafka and writes into appropriate partitions in file system. For instance, the job is configured to use a bucketing sink which writes to /data/date=${date}/hour=${hour}.

How to detect that the partition is ready to be used so that a corresponding airflow pipeline can do some batch processing on top of that hour?

Comment: This looks like a variation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094729/process-elements-after-sinking-to-destination, yes?

Comment: No, the last question assumes a certain way of doing it, while this asks more about what would be the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the implementation of the [ContinuousFileMonitoringSource](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction.html), to see how it monitors the file system. And then do something similar to what David Anderson suggested in your other question, re creating a custom ProcessFunction.